# Random выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Пишу

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Random является пространством имён, но используется как тип.

Как пофиксить?

Comment: `System.Random rand = new System.Random();`

Comment: еще можно в самом начале кода написать `using System;`, тогда изначальный код заработал бы без изменений.

Comment: @aepot [Не заработал бы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TKzA.png). Тут скорей всего псевдонимы надо применять, нечто такое `using Rand = System.Random;` и дальше `Rand random = new Rand();`. Ну а вообще тут явно проблема со структурой приложения, кто в здравом уме будет называть namespace `Random`...

Answer (score 0):

Вот так все работает:

```
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(rand.Next().ToString());
  }
}
```